# UseAdaptiveSizePolicy and other jvm opts

Tags: java, jvm

The JVM option -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy is defined as part of the hotspot ergonomics and can be specified with throughput or the pause time priority.

However, my question is - is it right to have the other jvm options like NewSize and SurvivorRatio mentioned along with it?. What exactly is the impact of doing that?

Answer (score 16):

Just FYI, `-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` [is enabled by default](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) in any recent version of the Sun JVM.

Also, I found [an article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rprf_hotspot_parms.html):

> **Avoid trouble**: `-XX:SurvivorRatio=`
>   option is incompatible with the JVM
>   parameter `-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`.
>   Please use either one according to
>   your situation.

I couldn't find a definitive answer for `NewSize`, but it appears it sets the *initial* young generation size, not permanent, so it's not mutually exclusive with `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`.

However, here's a bunch of articles:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html
- http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/garbagecollection2/

In most cases, however, if you're tuning `SurvivorRatio` will want to tune `NewSize` and `MaxNewSize`.

Comment: How to close adaptive size policy?

Comment: @skytree if you mean _disable_, then `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`, notice the `+/-`

Answer (score 6):

My experience with combinations of non-standard options (-X) is that they behave slightly different among JVM versions and platforms.

If you want to be really sure about which is the result of a set of options, check the real JVM values with `jmap -heap` if possible, e.g.

```
Client compiler detected.
JVM version is 1.5.0_14-b03

using thread-local object allocation.
Mark Sweep Compact GC

Heap Configuration:
    MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
    MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
    MaxHeapSize = 209715200 (200.0MB)
    NewSize = 2228224 (2.125MB)
    MaxNewSize = 4294901760 (4095.9375MB)
    OldSize = 1441792 (1.375MB)
    NewRatio = 8
    SurvivorRatio = 32
    PermSize = 8388608 (8.0MB)
    MaxPermSize = 134217728 (128.0MB)
[...]
```