# Why does the ratio between each survivor space and eden does not match SurvivorRatio?

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

> The [SurvivorRatio](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abeil/index.html) parameter controls the size of the two survivor spaces. For example, -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 sets the ratio between each survivor space and eden to be 1:6, each survivor space will be one eighth of the young generation.

Why does the space capacity of survivor and eden not match SurvivorRatio, as below? Produced by `jmap -heap 15760`.

```
Attaching to process ID 15760, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.80-b11

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 8 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 100
   MaxHeapSize      = 4294967296 (4096.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 1074266112 (1024.5MB)
   used     = 276841328 (264.01646423339844MB)
   free     = 797424784 (760.4835357666016MB)
   25.770274693352704% used
From Space:
   capacity = 178782208 (170.5MB)
   used     = 56996280 (54.35588836669922MB)
   free     = 121785928 (116.14411163330078MB)
   31.880286432081654% used
To Space:
   capacity = 178782208 (170.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 178782208 (170.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 2863661056 (2731.0MB)
   used     = 98320 (0.0937652587890625MB)
   free     = 2863562736 (2730.906234741211MB)
   0.003433367220397748% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 47710208 (45.5MB)
   used     = 47664440 (45.45635223388672MB)
   free     = 45768 (0.04364776611328125MB)
   99.90407084370707% used

26132 interned Strings occupying 2933384 bytes.
```

Comment: This is weird, seems you actual SurvivorRation is 6, not 8.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`SurvivorRatio = 8` means that each survivor space takes 1/8th of the young generation whose size is Eden + To + From. In your case The young generation size is 1365.5 MB and 1/8th of that would be 170,69 - assuming there's some rounding involved (or some other small space) the values are sound.</strike>

**Update:** I had some misconception here. The values in your case would be valid, the spaces probably just haven't used their maximum capacity yet.

Try running a test with `Xms=<value of Xmx>`.

In my case (with a jdk 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8) I used `SurvivorRatio=10` and got the following results (Java 8 had some slight differences):

```
Heap Configuration:
  ...   
  SurvivorRatio    = 10
  ...

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
  capacity = 596508672 (568.875MB)  //Java 8 reported 569.5 here
  used     = 536159440 (511.3214874267578MB)
  free     = 60349232 (57.55351257324219MB)
  89.8829246190741% used
From Space:
  capacity = 59637760 (56.875MB)    //Java 8 reported 56.5 here
  used     = 59626360 (56.86412811279297MB)
  free     = 11400 (0.01087188720703125MB)
  99.9808845939217% used
To Space:
  capacity = 59637760 (56.875MB)    //Java 8 reported 56.5 here
  used     = 0 (0.0MB)
  free     = 59637760 (56.875MB)
  0.0% used
```

As you can see, both survivor spaces are exactly 10% the size of the eden space. Without `Xms=<Xmx>` I got way lower percentages as the spaces didn't have to be increased yet.

**Update 2:**

Apparantly the OP's spaces already aquired their maximum capacity with young generation having 1365 MB max (which is 33% of the 4096 MB max heap size). In that case the values look like the survivor ratio being 6 (i.e. each survivor space taking 1/8th of eden space) but jmap reporting a ratio of 8 indicates some kind of error/bug here (I did my tests with JVM version 21.0-b17 and 25.40-b25, i.e. the OP's version 24.80-b11 is somewhere in between).

**Update 3:**

I reran my tests twice with jdk 7:

No 1.: no `SurvivorRatio` set, i.e. default of 8 should be used:

```
Heap Configuration:
   ...
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   ...

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 536870912 (512.0MB)
   ...
From Space:
   capacity = 89456640 (85.3125MB)
   ...
To Space:
   capacity = 89456640 (85.3125MB)
   ...
```

No 2.: explicit `SurvivorRatio=8` set:

```
Heap Configuration:
   ...
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   ...

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 572653568 (546.125MB)
   ...
From Space:
   capacity = 71565312 (68.25MB)
   ...
To Space:
   capacity = 71565312 (68.25MB)
   ...
```

As you can see there's a difference in the ratio even though a value of 8 is reported for both cases. Only the second case where the ratio was explicitly set to 8 fits the equation provided in the documentation which indicates in the default case there's some other ratio being used and jmap either reports a wrong ratio or the actual size calculation use a different value/formula.

From the values the formulas look like this:

- explicit survivor ratio: `size(survior space) = size(eden space)/survivorRatio` (example: `546.125 / 8 = 68.25` - see test 2)
- implicit/default survivor ratio: `size(survior space) = size(young generation)/survivorRatio` (example: `682 / 8 = 85.25`- see test 1, values rounded a bit)

Note: this also is true for jdk 1.8.

Comment: @YanhuiZhou the problem is: you set  `SurvivorRatio=6` but jmap reports `SurvivorRatio=8` - that indicates your settings are not used (8 is the default). Note that the documentation you posted is 6 years old and probably doesn't apply to current JVMs anymore .

Comment: @YanhuiZhou also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634465/useadaptivesizepolicy-and-other-jvm-opts - Chances are you didn't disable `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` so setting the survior ratio won't work.

Comment: I am not set SurvivorRatio=6, that is just the reference content from the url.

Comment: @YanhuiZhou I updated the answer, there was a misconception. With the default survivor ratio of 8 each survivor space has a maximum of 10% of the young generation (1 + 1 + 8). If the values you get don't match that simply means the spaces didn't require their maximum capacity yet.

Comment: @YanhuiZhou I added another 2 updates on tests I did on my machine. Those indicate the ratio of 8 being reported in your case is wrong (setting the ratio to 8 explicitly yields the correct sizes).

Comment: I have added explanation for the difference in explicit and implicit ratio cases in an answer below

Answer (score 2):

It seems that at some time the formula for calculating the eden / survivor space size has changed.

See to https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17980811/, lines 52 to 54:

> The survivor ratio's are calculated "raw", unlike the default gc, which adds 2 to the ratio value. We need to make sure the values are valid before using them.

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected and was looking for. As in "read the code, the documentation lies" ;)

Comment: @ThomasKläger I accidentally stumbled against this, but i don't think this is correct. The `plus 2` is referenced here : http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1573. That's not a `SurvivorRatio - 2` at all...

Answer (score 1):

Your eden to survivor ratio is 6:1, as the there is two survivors, the ratio of the survivors to young space is 1/8th

The Eden has a capacity of 1024.5 MB and 1024.5 / 6 = 107.75 which is pretty close to the 107.5 MB for each survivor spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon, and to clarify the behaviour stated in [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36764618/11389917), the difference in two cases is due to the way in which the cases of explicitly specifying `SurvivorRatio` flag and not specifying the same, are handled. Spoiler alert - jmap output (i.e. SurvivorRatio = 8) is also not exactly wrong. How, you ask? Follow along:

There are 3 options present related to Survivor ratio - `SurvivorRatio`, `MinSurvivorRatio`, and `InitialSurvivorRatio`. The defaults for these (can be found in source code [gc_globals.hpp](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6aa197667ad05bd93adf3afc7b06adbfb2b18a22/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gc_globals.hpp#L470)) are 8, 3, and 8 respectively. Also from source code it is clear that:

- `SurvivorRatio` considers the ratio Eden:Survivor
- `MinSurvivorRatio` and `InitialSurvivorRatio` consider the ratio YoungGen:Survivor

As per [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6368557) Oracle bug ticket,

> The UseParallelGC collector uses
> the command line flags `MinSurvivorRatio` and `InitialSurvivorRatio`.

(Note that actually `Parallel scavenge` is the name of GC, and UseParallelGC is the flag to explicitly tell JVM to use this GC.)

And as per [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6362902) Oracle bug ticket,

> Assigning `SurivorRatio` a value of `k` will yield `InitialSurvivorRatio=(k+2)` and `MinSurvivorRatio=(k+2)` in case of `Parallel Scavenger`

(source code: [parallelArguments.cpp](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6aa197667ad05bd93adf3afc7b06adbfb2b18a22/src/hotspot/share/gc/parallel/parallelArguments.cpp#L69)) (Parallel Scavenger is default GC. As can be seen in code, the two flags will be assigned values in this manner only if the SurivorRatio is specified but these two flags are not specified.)

If `SurvivorRatio` and the other two flags are not specified, the defaults specified in `gc_globals.hpp` would be used. Parallel Scavenger would only care about `MinSurvivorRatio` and `InitialSurvivorRatio` defaults.

Hence,

- If SurvivorRatio=8 option is specified (and the other two not), (k+2=10), it yields both min and initial YoungGen:Survivor ratio as 10:1
- If none of the 3 flags specified, (no modification, use default) it yields  initial (and min) YoungGen:Survivor ratio as 8:1 (and 3:1).

In both cases, the value for SurvivorRatio is 8, hence jmap will output 8.

This answer assumes that the `XX:UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` flag is disabled (explicitly, as it is enabled by default), since as per IBM [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=thjvmshu-sun-hotspot-jvm-tuning-parameters-solaris-hp-ux):

> Avoid trouble: -XX:SurvivorRatio= option is incompatible with the JVM parameter -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy. Please use either one according to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1573

I think the meaning of this code is that if the user does not explicitly set the value of SurvivorRatio, the default value SurvivorRatio=8 is used. In that case, the Survivor memory is calculated as YoungSize/SurvivorRatio, so the ratio of s0:s1:Eden would be 1:1:6.

However, if the user explicitly sets the value of SurvivorRatio to 8, then the formula for calculating the Survivor memory becomes YoungSize/(SurvivorRatio+2). In this case, the ratio of s0:s1:Eden would be 1:1:8.

In summary, without an explicit user-defined SurvivorRatio, the default 1:1:6 ratio is used. But if the user configures SurvivorRatio=8, then the ratio changes to 1:1:8 to account for the +2 adjustment to the denominator. This allows the user-defined SurvivorRatio to work properly with the Parallel Scavenge collector.